# Are buildings currently being upgraded able to function during clan war?

Tags: clash-of-clans

If a war is started and some of my defensive buildings are being upgraded, are they able to defend my base during war?

I know they don't function in normal play until the upgrade is finished, but war bases are different to some degree.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Whatever the highest level your buildings are before the end of the preparation day is the level of those buildings during the war.  Anything under construction in your "normal" base will revert to the level it was before you started the upgrade in your "war" base.

This is from the [Clan Wars FAQ](http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/232849-Clan-Wars-FAQ), written by a SuperCell employee:

> The war base can not be directly upgraded or rearranged, but will instead mimic the arrangement and highest completed upgrade levels of your village during the preparation day. Buildings and traps will never be “under construction” in your war base.

Comment: It's worth noting that new buildings (ie when you're building a level 1 building) are available immediately in clan wars (providing you started building them before the war started of course).

Answer (score 10):

My clan has been in wars since the Clan War update, and I can give a more complete answer with regards to the most current update as of February 2015.

All buildings - defensive, offensive, town hall, any except clan castle - will be reflected in your war base at their highest COMPLETED level, all the way to the end of Prep Day. Once Prep Day ends, your entire war base is set in stone. This means that if you started a L3 Xbow, but it will not finish until after Prep Day is over, it will remain at L2 in your war base, unless you decide to finish it early with gems.. in which case it would be L3 for war.

NEW structures that you start building before or during Prep Day will be automatically included in your war base at L1 - even if they are still unfinished in your normal base - provided you edit your war base and place them in time. This is especially important for new town halls. For example, if you finish a L9 town hall during Prep Day, you could start your 2 new Xbows, air defenses, archer tower, etc.. and they will all be available to be placed in your war base at L1, even if they are still under construction when Prep Day ends.

Town hall upgrades completed during Prep Day will also show up now on the clan war base map. However, upgraded clan castles will NOT reflect their new, higher troop capacity, unless it finishes BEFORE Prep Day begins. That is the only exception I am aware of to date. But overall, upgrading bases are more fluid than ever until Battle Day.

Comment: The note about clan castles on the war map is pretty important. +1 for that alone.

Comment: The exception with the clan castle is probably because it has important role in prep day itself.