# Why doesn't my war castle have my upgraded capacity?

Tags: clash-of-clans

When I upgraded my clan castle before a war, it went from holding 15 troops to 20. My war clan castle still says 15 troops, though. My clan castle was done upgrading before war started! At my regular village, it holds 20, but war base says 15 troops. Why is this happening?

Comment: What do you mean by *"before war started"*, do you mean War Day? Prep Day?, can you be absolutely sure that Prep Day didn't start before you Clan Castle finished as according to [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/205044/30879) the Clan Castle has to have been finished before Prep Day Starts

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is a perfectly fine question. I actually had this happen to me.

Answer (score 2):

When buildings finish upgrading during Preparation Day, your war base will reflect those upgrades. This includes your clan castle, and you can confirm this by scouting your own war base from the war map and selecting your clan castle.

However, the war map itself is not updated, and this is where donations take place. Once the war map itself is generated, it does not change, even if individual war bases have buildings that are newly created or upgraded. As a result, the donation capacity does not change since donations are mechanically tied to the war map and not your war base.

So, your war base will reflect your upgraded clan castle, which contains more hit points than it did before. But the war map will not reflect the upgrade so you'll still only have 15 spaces for troop donations for the current war.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I had the same experience. During the preparation day, my clan castle has done upgrading (hours before the battle day). I noticed that the capacity is still 15 instead of 20. It is mentioned in the wiki that the **highest completed upgrade levels of your village during the preparation day.**  will be applied but the clan castle I think has an exception.

Source: [Clash of Clans Wikia - War: The War Map (2nd question)](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Clan_Wars_FAQ#How_is_my_war_base_different_from_my_village.3F)

Comment: You're almost there. If you scout your own war base, you'd note that the clan castle was at the upgraded level, even though the capacity on your map was still 15.